# Azure AD Connect users excluded from sync

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, entra-id

We have been using Azure AD Connect for about 18 months without any major sync issues. However, this week we have suddenly encountered a scenario where a large set of certain users are being excluded from the sync. Thankfully, this is only happening in our staging Azure AD instance, but I want to be prepared for when/if this occurs in production. All of these users are created with .NET code, so I'm sure there must be a common reason they aren't syncing, but we can't figure out what it is.

In an effort to get things working again, I ran a full sync that had the opposite effect -- it deleted a large number of users from Azure AD . I am unable to get any of those users to sync with Azure AD again.

One thing that is really strange is that I can run Get-ADUser and retrieve the user by the Azure AD Connect troubleshooting tool is unable to see the user.

**Example:**

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-aduser x.y -properties *

AccountExpirationDate                :
accountExpires                       : 9223372036854775807
AccountLockoutTime                   :
AccountNotDelegated                  : False
AllowReversiblePasswordEncryption    : False
AuthenticationPolicy                 : {}
AuthenticationPolicySilo             : {}
BadLogonCount                        : 0
badPasswordTime                      : 0
badPwdCount                          : 0
CannotChangePassword                 : False
CanonicalName                        : xxxxx.xxxxx.com/yyyyyy/x.y
Certificates                         : {}
City                                 :
CN                                   : x.y
codePage                             : 0
Company                              :
CompoundIdentitySupported            : {}
Country                              :
countryCode                          : 0
Created                              : 11/11/2019 3:37:45 PM
createTimeStamp                      : 11/11/2019 3:37:45 PM
Deleted                              :
Department                           :
Description                          :
DisplayName                          : x y
DistinguishedName                    : CN=x.y,OU=yyyyyy,DC=xxxxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=com
Division                             :
DoesNotRequirePreAuth                : False
dSCorePropagationData                : {1/1/1601 12:00:00 AM}
EmailAddress                         : x.y@test.com
EmployeeID                           :
EmployeeNumber                       :
Enabled                              : True
Fax                                  :
GivenName                            : x
HomeDirectory                        :
HomedirRequired                      : False
HomeDrive                            :
HomePage                             :
HomePhone                            :
Initials                             :
instanceType                         : 4
isDeleted                            :
KerberosEncryptionType               : {}
LastBadPasswordAttempt               :
LastKnownParent                      :
lastLogoff                           : 0
lastLogon                            : 0
LastLogonDate                        :
LockedOut                            : False
logonCount                           : 0
LogonWorkstations                    :
mail                                 : x.y@test.com
Manager                              :
MemberOf                             : {CN=yyyyyy RD Users,OU=yyyyyy,DC=xxxxx,DC=
MNSLogonAccount                      : False
MobilePhone                          :
Modified                             : 11/11/2019 3:37:45 PM
modifyTimeStamp                      : 11/11/2019 3:37:45 PM
msDS-User-Account-Control-Computed   : 0
Name                                 : x.y
nTSecurityDescriptor                 : System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurity
ObjectCategory                       : CN=Person,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=xxxxx,DC=xxxxx,
ObjectClass                          : user
ObjectGUID                           : 47e489c9-3c07-4e0f-a7a8-9a8035d7250d
objectSid                            : S-1-5-21-2788353538-1765426516-1583780121-6489
Office                               :
OfficePhone                          :
Organization                         :
OtherName                            :
PasswordExpired                      : False
PasswordLastSet                      : 11/11/2019 3:37:45 PM
PasswordNeverExpires                 : False
PasswordNotRequired                  : True
POBox                                :
PostalCode                           :
PrimaryGroup                         : CN=Domain Users,CN=Users,DC=xxxxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=com
primaryGroupID                       : 513
PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount : {}
ProfilePath                          :
ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion      : False
pwdLastSet                           : 132179602657179811
SamAccountName                       : x.y
sAMAccountType                       : 805306368
ScriptPath                           :
sDRightsEffective                    : 15
ServicePrincipalNames                : {}
SID                                  : S-1-5-21-2788353538-1765426516-1583780121-6489
SIDHistory                           : {}
SmartcardLogonRequired               : False
sn                                   : y
State                                :
StreetAddress                        :
Surname                              : y
Title                                :
TrustedForDelegation                 : False
TrustedToAuthForDelegation           : False
UseDESKeyOnly                        : False
userAccountControl                   : 544
userCertificate                      : {}
UserPrincipalName                    : x.y@xxxxx.xxxxx.com
uSNChanged                           : 1587587
uSNCreated                           : 1587583
whenChanged                          : 11/11/2019 3:37:45 PM
whenCreated                          : 11/11/2019 3:37:45 PM
```

**Azure AD Connect troubleshooting tool**
When I enter the user DN in the Azure AD Connect troubleshooting tool I receive the error message:

> Could not find an object in on-premises AD with distinguishedName="CN=x.y,OU=xxxxxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=xxxxx,DC=com".

I'm really stuck at this point and can't figure out how to move forward. None of the Azure AD Connect docs have provided guidance on how I might be able to figure it out.

Comment: Have you looked at the deleted user to see if you find those users for recovery?

Comment: Try to follow the steps here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/tshoot-connect-object-not-syncing
Reading the logs should give you a clue to why the users were deleted.